# How to check if else (varchar 0101010) for date in gridview C#(ASP.net) when i get db

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

How to check if else (varchar 0101010) for date in gridview C#(ASP.net) when i get db

[image: Image with explanation]

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell StatusDate = e.Row.Cells[3];

    //how to set if else or swith case (0000000)(check if else 1 on bounddatarow)

     }
 }
```

Comment: This is some kind of test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.

This solution uses `Dictionary` to map `DayOfWeek`

```
var dictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>()
    .Select((day, index) => 
            new 
            {
                index,
                day
            })
    .ToDictionary(k=>k.index, v=>v.day);



var date_string = string.Join(",", "1010101".Select((chr,index) => new {chr,index}).Where(e=>e.chr == '1').Select(c=>dictionary[c.index]));
```

**Update:**

if you are using .Net 2.0 use this code.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, DayOfWeek>(); 
    int i=0;
    foreach(DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
    {
        dict.Add(i++,day);
    }


    List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>();

    i=0;
    foreach(var c in "1010101")
    {
        if(c=='1')
        {
            days.Add(dict[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    string.Join(",",days).Dump();
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fi7T9q)

Comment: i can't use like this / Visual studio 2005 /sql 2008 r2/ framwork 2.0

Comment: Updated answer for `2.0`, Extension methods are not available in `2.0`.